# System image backup and restore on two different servers

Tags: debian-squeeze

I am still new to the system administration in Linux. So I need your help on the following case:

We have a debian 6 server which was installed long time ago. It has different partitions that are almost becoming full. The server has started complaining for more space and to expand them it's impossible since the partitions were created without using LVM (Logical Volume Manager). So I've installed another server with the same version of OS and kernel of the existing server with the partitions that support LVM. However, I am challenged on how I can move all the data and system configuration to the new server because:
1. I am wondering if I create an image of the existing server and restore it to the new server I will get the same state of the old server, therefore loosing the LVM support on the new server which is the subject to this change.
2. The filesystem for the new server has the Ext4 extension while the old server has Ext3 extension. Won't there be incompatibility?

Note that both servers are virtual servers managed by Vmware.

Can someone gives me advice on how I can go about it? I will be very grateful to get your support.

Thanks

Comment: Would adding more disk via nfs be an option?

Comment: I avoided that as the server is busy responding to the customers' requests, and that's why i wanted to deal with another server to avoid any human error that can crash the system